# iOS TabBarController with custom MoreNavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to create a custom `UITabBarController` that instead of showing a "more" view controller, I want my tabs to be scrollable. I've already created a custom `UITabBar` with a `collectionView` with my tabs and it works great.

However when I add more than 5 tabs, the more navigation controller comes into play. I need that to be my custom Navigation Controller that allows the NavigationBar and the TabBar to hide themselves as the user scrolls, however, since the default MoreNavigationController is a normal UINavigationController, the desired behaviour does not occur. I've tried embedding my ViewController in my custom NavigationController before adding it to the TabBarController, but (as expected) since the MoreNavigationController is already managing all the ViewControllers after the 5th, it has no effect.

I've tried overriding UITabBarController's `var moreNavigationController: UINavigationController` and return my custom NavigationController. However, when I run my app it crashes with the following message:

`-[MyApp.ScrollingNavController setMoreViewControllers:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffbce831000
2018-05-23 13:45:27.573611+0300 MyApp[6000:190109] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.ScrollingNavController setMoreViewControllers:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffbce831000'`

I do not know how to overcome this problem, so if anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add more code here , Also the error is saying there is no method available in ScrollingNavController verify whether you opened up the method in .h file

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have a feeling you'll need to create a custom tab bar controller for this...

Comment: Thanks guys. I've created a custom TabBarCotnroller, and I'm trying to get rid of the MoreNavigationController. I've tried adding the required method but I still get the error as follows `@objc func setMoreViewControllers(viewControllers: [UIViewController]) {}`. I'm writing in Swift

Comment: @LucasP. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, in a very custom, complex and unmaintainable way unfortunately... Maybe I'll try packing it into a library and put it on GitHub when I find the time. The idea is this: A custom `UITabBarController` that has an array of `UIViewController`s. Each time, only a single VC is assigned as the TabBar's `viewControllers`, and I handle the swapping of VCs manually. This way I never go over the "5 tabs limit." On top of it there is a collection view that can show as many VCs as I need. It's a messy solution but it works. I stand against it, as per the platform guidelines, but sometimes... Clients.